# Delphi Volume control by keyboard

Tags: delphi, keyboard, volume

I recently had to replace a keyboard and this one ( GE 98552 ) does not have programmable buttons along the top and I miss the up/down volume buttons. it has 9 special buttons but none for volume and this model is not programmable. DUH!

I am a long-time Delphi programmer but never messed with the multimedia stuff.

Can anyone suggest some code to assign to say the "+" and "-" keys on the numeric pad that will change the volume up and down? I never use those two buttons so I would not be giving up functionality.

Thanks

Frank

Comment: Windows XP or below, or Windows Vista+?

Comment: You've got two separate problems in there: (1) How to change the volume up/down (2) How to hook up the keyboard so the volume can be changed in response to some keys. You should have asked two question. Even better, do a SO search for `[delphi] hook keyboard` - there are so many answers I'd have a hard time picking only one to link. Next do a search for `[delphi] volume control` - again, multiple answers, can't link only one.

Answer (score 1):

one idea: you can create a small app. that registers global hotkeys(let's say ctrl+num + and ctrl+num -) that will modify volume, hope this helps to some degree...
I also ran across this code http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/multimedia/change_the_sound_cards_volume.html but I can't test it right now...
and to register/unregister global hot key http://www.delphidabbler.com/tips/16